# Which definition is used for the verb "beset"?

Tags: word-usage

Now reading [**this,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/soleimanis-body-arrives-iran-trump-044541342.html), the 4th paragraph says,

> Iran has promised “harsh revenge" for the U.S. attack, which shocked Iranians across all political lines. Many saw Soleimani as a pillar of the Islamic Republic at a moment when it is ***beset*** by U.S. sanctions and recent anti-government protests.

Which definition is the above mentioned bold italic verb "beset" defined by?

From Merriam Unabridged,

> 1a :  to set at intervals :  stud especially with ornaments
>
> b :  to cover especially with plant growth
>   
>   :  fill or strew especially with impediments
>
> 2
>   :  plague, trouble, harass :  weigh down :  dog, bedevil
>
> 3
>   a :  to set upon :  attack repeatedly :  assail
>
> b :  to lay siege to :  surround so as to compel surrender :  besiege
>
> c :  to occupy, take possession of, or overrun in such a way as to prevent free passage :  choke off :  blockade
>
> d (1) :  to close or hem in :  encompass, surround
>
> (2) :  to surround (something, such as a task or problem) with immaterial or nonphysical perils or obstacles
>
> (3) :  to surround (something, such as a ship) on all sides with ice so that free movement is totally checked — used of ice fields

Thank you for your support.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you :)

Comment: It's definition #2 in your context.Iran is *plagued, harassed, weighed down* by US sanctions and anti-government protests..It's worth noting that most other dictionaries give that definition ***first***. I'd guess that sense is *way* more common than the ***beset = studded** [with jewels, etc.]* definition, which is a bit dated/literary today. Try checking more than one dictionary (or at least not always using M-W) in future.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Okay, Thank you for advice.(m_m).

Comment: But I don't understand why there is a close vote. If this question is not about **English**, then what will be left?

Comment: It's my closevote. I accept that the first definition in MW might have misled you briefly (but surely it's obvious that one wouldn't fit your context). But if I just search for ***define beset***, I don't even have to leave the Google home page - the first snippet result gives the definition *(of a problem or difficulty) **trouble** (someone or something) **persistently**.* Just because one dictionary lists one "less common" definition first doesn't justify asking such a "basic meaning" question here, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So you did. Why do you think it is a "basic" question? There are other tons of "too"basic questions over there.

Comment: I consider it "basic" because the relevant definition came up *first* in all the other dictionaries I checked, as well as being the sense given by the first "results snippet view" as per my search above. In which context it's worth noting that that Google snippet view also gives the "studded, inlaid" definition - which it specifically flags as ARCHAIC.